# Adding an API controller to an ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Here is the controller scaffolded and edited.

```
namespace TheAspNetCoreProject
{
    [Route("api/TheApi")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TheApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetInfo()
        {
            return Ok("Foo");
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping to see it at `/api/TheApi/` or `/api/TheApi/Info` or `/api/TheApi/GetInfo` but nothing.

The scaffolding didn't do anything to `Startup.cs`, however it's not mentioned for example in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) that anything is needed in `Startup.cs` -- which sounds unlikely.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Show us your Startup file

Answer (score 2):

I've just fired up VS and did a new .net core Web Api project from template and it works as you would expect to work:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/TheApi")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
    [HttpGet("OtherGet")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> OtherGet()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Valid urls:

- https://localhost:44308/api/TheApi -->calls the Get method
- https://localhost:44308/api/TheApi/Get -->calls the Get method
- https://localhost:44308/api/TheApi/OtherGet -->calls the OtherGet method, that have the OtherGet route name in the HttpGet annotation.

Startup.cs looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

**UPDATE:** Also keep in mind that you can not have multiple GET/POST etc methods in one controller, only if you use the annotation for the others (or for all of them) like I did with OtherGet: HttpGet("OtherGet")]. If you don't use this annotation and have multiple GET, POST etc methods you will have exception: `AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.`

Comment: That was good idea -- starting a new webAPI project. And indeed the difference in `Startup.cs` that I had found is plain to see.

Comment: Glad to hear, please accept answer if it helped you :)
Also keep in mind that you can not have multiple get/post etc methods in one controller, only if you use the annotation for the others (or all of them) like I did with OtherGet: HttpGet("OtherGet")]. If you don't use this annotation and have multiple GET, POST etc methods you will have exception: AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of very unpleasant trial and error I can now report that it was indeed `Startup.cs` that needed to be updated -- scaffolding the webAPI controller had not updated it.

In my

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
```

I had

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

and it needed to be changed to

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers(); // Added for webAPI.
            });
```

Comment: I have this endpoints.MapControllers(); in my configure, still, when I do localhost:8090/WeatherForecast I get 404.

Answer (score -1):

By default, Web API routes are defined like so: `api/{controller}`. Notice there is no `{action}` present.

They are this way to conform to the REST (Representational state transfer) way of doing things. It is based on the notion of resources and verbs that are applied to them; commonly GET, UPDATE, POST, DELETE.

So with the default route, this would match:

`GET api/TheApi`

```
namespace TheAspNetCoreProject
{
    [Route("api/TheApi")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TheApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("Foo");
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the route can always be changed to be more RPC-like.

Comment: So, it is exactly what OP says:  "was hoping to see it at /api/TheApi/"

Comment: "By default, Web API routes are defined like so: api/{controller}" it is not true for ASP.NET Core

Comment: You just remove `[HttpGet]` and rename action and hope that it should work?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Didn’t see it was for Core; That would work in non-Core.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about dotnet core 3.1